# Automatically set next year in timeline

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am building a timeline and would like to have years automatically be increased according to months.

Here is my current timeline:

[image]

I have a button, that is adding +1 column = (+1 month). So if I click button, following macro is triggered:

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("K:K").Copy
    .Columns("L:L").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End With
```

In screenshot attached after month is again `January`, year should already be 2021.

I have tried to do so:

**B33**

```
=YEAR(OtherData!$P$17)
```

**C33** (all other cells to the right)

```
=YEAR(OtherData!$P$17)+IF(B34="January";1;0)
```

this works, but then I get 2021 only in M33. How to make formula copy previous cell until `January` is reached in row 34?

---

**EDIT:**

This seems to work **C33** (all other cells to the right):

```
=IF(C34="January";YEAR(OtherData!$P$17)+IF(C34="January";1;0);B33)
```

but after VBA is triggered, everything gets messed up again...

---

**EDIT 2:**

I think formula is now correct, but macro should be edited somehow to copy paste from the end all the time and not operate with defined cells like now K and L.

OR

Just fill range C33 -> to the right with formula  `=IF(C34="January";YEAR(OtherData!$P$17)+IF(C34="January";1;0);B33)` after triggering the macro. Have to find `UsedRange` probably somehow.

---

**EDIT 3:**

This seems to be like working solution:

```
Sub Add_One_Year()

    Dim lColumn As Long

    With Sheet1
        .Range("L:L").Copy
        .Columns("K:K").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End With

    lColumn = CashflowSheet.Cells(33, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Sheet1.Range(Cells(33, 3), Cells(33, lColumn)).Formula = "=IF(C34=""January"",YEAR(OtherData!$P$17)+IF(C34=""January"",1,0),B33)"

    'MsgBox ("The last used column is: " & lColumn)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try and figure the year out - add an actual date to the cell and format it to show the month or year as required.  When you add a month the year will automatically increase in January.

Add your first date into cell `B34` and give a custom number format of `mmmm`.  In cell `B33` use the formula `=B34` and give a custom number format of `yyyy`.

Execute this code to add the next month:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim LastCol As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastCol = .Cells(34, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With .Cells(34, LastCol + 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=EOMONTH(RC[-1],0)+1"
            .NumberFormat = "MMMM"
        End With
        With .Cells(33, LastCol + 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C"
            .NumberFormat = "YYYY"
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```